# scrapy not scrape page if subdomain have underscore

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I try scrape pages contain underscore in subdomain, etc: https://taxi-3-extreme-rush_1.en.softonic.com

I check specifications and i see that subdomain can contain underscore.
Also i was try use link.encode('idna'), but also not works.

And i have error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 60, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 285, in download_request
    method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1596, in request
    endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1580, in _getEndpoint
    return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1456, in endpointForURI
    uri.port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 59, in creatorForNetloc
    return ScrapyClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode("ascii"), self.getContext())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1201, in __init__
    self._hostnameBytes = _idnaBytes(hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 87, in _idnaBytes
    return idna.encode(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 355, in encode
    result.append(alabel(label))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 276, in alabel
    check_label(label)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 253, in check_label
    raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {0} at position {1} of {2} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+005F at position 20 of u'taxi-3-extreme-rush_1' not allowed
```

Answer (score 4):

A workaround:

```
import idna


idna.idnadata.codepoint_classes['PVALID'] = tuple(
    sorted(list(idna.idnadata.codepoint_classes['PVALID']) + [0x5f0000005f])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's an issue with Twisted.

There's an issue with a solution regarding it [here](http://dornkirk.twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8190):

> Looking at Twisted's code, it'll use the ​idna library if available. If I pip uninstall idna and issue the same request again, it is successful.
>
> idna gets installed with either pip install twisted[tls] or pip install treq.

I've tried uninstalling idna via `pip uninstall idna` and the request, indeed, goes through.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug with TLS connections only. Fetching the http:// URL gets the redirect correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Selenium and it can parse correctly. I can verify this because if I disable the spider's middleware (where my Selenium code is). The same error is thrown.

```
raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {0} at position {1} of {2} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
idna.core.InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+005F at position 3 of 'xyx_abc' not allowed
```